# How am i overriding this C++ inherited member function without the virtual keyword being used?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a small program to demonstrate simple inheritance. I am defining a Dog class which is derived from Mammal. Both classes share a simple member function called ToString(). How is Dog overriding the implementation in the Mammal class, when i'm not using the virtual keyword? (Do i even need to use the virtual keyword to override member functions?)

mammal.h

```
#ifndef MAMMAL_H_INCLUDED
#define MAMMAL_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Mammal
{
    public:
        std::string ToString();
};

#endif // MAMMAL_H_INCLUDED
```

mammal.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "mammal.h"

std::string Mammal::ToString()
{
    return "I am a Mammal!";
}
```

dog.h

```
#ifndef DOG_H_INCLUDED
#define DOG_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include "mammal.h"

class Dog : public Mammal
{
    public:
        std::string ToString();
};

#endif // DOG_H_INCLUDED
```

dog.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "dog.h"

std::string Dog::ToString()
{
    return "I am a Dog!";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dog.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Dog d;
    std::cout << d.ToString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
I am a Dog!
```

I'm using MingW on Windows via Code::Blocks.

Comment: Think masking rather than overriding.

Comment: oh god I have the same damn assignment in front of me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not *overriding* the `ToString` method in the base class as the base class method is not `virtual`. It is simply hiding that function with a function with an identical signature.

When you call `ToString()` on a `Dog` object the `Dog::ToString` method is called. Why would it call any other `ToString()` method; the `Dog::` declaration is the first one found? `virtual` dispatch would only happen (and only be needed) when being called through a pointer or reference to a base class object.

If you needed to call the base class method on a Dog object you would have to qualify it explicitly.

```
d.Mammal::ToString()
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code uses a Dog object directly, so when you call `ToString()`, it's statically bound to `Dog::ToString()`, and produces "I am a Dog!".

To demonstrate polymorphism you can start with a pointer (or reference) to the base class, but set it to refer to an object of the derived class:

```
Dog d;
Mammal &m = d;

std::cout << m.ToString(); // will produce "I am a Mammal!".
std::cout << d.ToString(); // will produce "I am a Dog!"
```

Invoked that way, if you make `ToString` virtual, the output will depend on the type of object pointed at instead of the type of the pointer/reference itself (so both of the invocations above would produce "I am a Dog!").

Answer (score 1):

Try add virtual at `ToString()` method in class Mammal. I think that is what you want.

```
class Mammal
{
    public:
        virtual std::string ToString();
};
```